# How to find the buildings (polygons) a user can see from a given location (point) and orientation (angle range)?

Tags: qgis, postgis, r, viewshed

I would like to retrieve the set of buildings I can see from a given location (point -lat,lng) and orientation (interval of angles) + certainly with a given depth (e.g. 100 meters). Ideally I would like as output something like:
from angle 1 to angle2 the user can see building 1, from angle 2 to angle3 we see building 2.

**Data =** Polygons representing the buildings of a city in shapefile.

**input:** a location and an orientation (angle range) to represent the visual perception of a person.

**output**:
    Version 1 - a list of {BuildingID}
    Version 2 (better)- list of {BuildingID, set of visible segments for each building (facade of buildings)}
Version 3 (ideal output) - a list of {buildingID, angle ranges}. (for exemple , from angle 1 to angle2 the user can see building 1, from angle 2 to angle3 we see building 2, etc..)

**Toolbox** I can use: PostGis, QGis, ruby, R

**start of solution for output v1:**
- creating a triangle representing the simplified visual scope of the user for a given point and orientation (internval of angle) and with a certain radius/deepth (e.g. 100 meters)
- computing intersection with buildings (e.g. ST_INTERSECTION) and visual scope. but a building can hide another one so pure intersection between visual scope and buildings might add no visible buildings. this issue need to be tackled.

**update: potential solution 2** 
- creating a triangle representing the simplified visual scope of the user for a given point and orientation (internval of angle) and with a certain radius/deepth (e.g. 100 meters) 
- creating n rays (LINE) at different angles filling the scopes.
- transforming all buildings(POLYGONS) into SEGMENTS/LINES
- for each ray finding the closest SEGMENT and the related buildingID. (ST_DISTANCE , ST_DWithin)
 at this stage so we should have a list of rays and the related building ID.
- then we could aggregate this list {ranges of angle,related building ID}.

Any idea about a more efficient way to do?

Answer (score 5):

Here's two examples.  First, a video showing off the new QGIS Globe plugin, but also showing PostGIS's 3d functions:

http://vimeo.com/54776907

Second, an example of viewshed analysis using PostGIS, R, and GRASS:

http://www.dimensionaledge.com/main/postgis/viewshed-analysis-in-postgis-using-plr-and-grass/

Comment: second link is not working?